# How to Change Chart Header Size and Color in Wijmo5

Tags: angular, wijmo

How to Change the Chart Header size and color in wijmo5(FlexChart) using angular2. I am trying to implement the headerStyle Property in Wijmo. But its not working.

my code:

```
<wj-flex-chart [itemsSource]="data" [bindingX]="'country'"
[chartType]="'Column'" [itemFormatter]="itemForChart" [header]="'SG Inventory Trend 2016'" 
header-style="{'font-size':'6'}"  [stacking]="'Stacked'" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" 
style="font-size:8pt;padding-left:20px" [options]="{'groupWidth':'15'}" 
[plotMargin]="'20 20 20 25'">
</wj-flex-chart>
```

But not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The headerStyle is a property and hence must be set as [headerStyle] like the other properties. However, there seems to be a bug that even after setting [headerStyle], the style does not get reflected. The default style does not get overridden. Will forward it to the devs for correction.